# Proving that a set of functions is not a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to disprove that $$V=\{f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb R \ \ | \ \exists \ n_f\in \Bbb N  \ \ s.t. \ f(n_f)=0\}$$

To do this I assumed infinite functions $k_1, k_2, k_3\dots$ all belonging to $V$ such that for any $n_{k_i} \in \Bbb N \ \ \exists \ \ $ a unique $k_i\in V$ where the function $k_i$ is zero at only $n_{k_i}$ but positive for all other natural numbers.

Now if we consider the vector addition of all these functions $$K(x)=k_1\oplus k_2\oplus k_3\dots$$ $$K(x)=(k_1+k_2+k_3\dots)(x)$$
Now this function will be positive for all natural numbers and thus is never zero for any natural number so this function does not belong to $V$ and thus $V$ is not a vector space as it is not closed under vector addition.

Is this proof correct? Or my assumption of infinite functions is not a valid way to prove what is required.

Comment: Even if your infinite sum was well defined, it would not contradict the ability of $V$ to be a vector space. Vector spaces do not need to be closed under infinite sums, and infinite sums are not in general even defined.

Comment: ... Luckily, you can get away with just a sum of two functions. As long as you pick two functions that have a unique root at different points (and are otherwise positive!), their sum will have no roots.

Comment: Consider the function $f(x) = \begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=0\\1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=1\\1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.  Are both $f$ and $g$ in your set?  Is $f+g$?

Comment: @preferred_anon  with a little care:  if $f(4)=-1$ and $g(4)=1$ the sum would have a zero.

Comment: @Randall You caught me before I edited it :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties of vector spaces only concern sums of a finite amount of terms. In general it may not even be possible to define a meaning to an infinite sum
in an arbitrary vector space $V$. Additionally, even if you define a notion of an infinite sum (by using limits) it is important to know that even if $V$ is a vector space you do not have necessarily have
$$ \sum_i v_i \in V$$
whenever $v_i \in V$ for all $i$. If this were the case $\sqrt 2$ would be a rational number !

Therefore do not concern yourself with infinite sums. Rather focus on the definition of a vector space (where only finite sums are considered).

It should be clear to you that the set $\{f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb R \}$ is a vector space so it only remains to prove that $V$ is not a vector subspace.

Clearly $0 \in V$, and $f \in V \implies  \lambda f \in V$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. The problem arises when summing two functions in $V$. Consider the constant function $1$ as well as the function
$$ \delta_x(n) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } n = x  \\ 0 & \text{ else}\end{cases}$$
then
$$ (1- \delta_x) + \delta_x \not \in  V$$

while $(1-\delta_x), \delta_x \in V$